# On Scroll Animate/SlideUp div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrollto

Hi guys I've been googling the whole day, but can't find the answer on how to achieve it. Once I scroll I want my div position at the bottom of the screen to slide up same to this site:

http://www.chanel.com/en_SG/. thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a bit of jQuery.

Here's some basic example you can use: (http://jsfiddle.net/ujmMk/5/)

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){ //onscroll
        var scrolleddown = false;//used to keep the state
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 1){ //if they've scrolled down
            if(scrolleddown == false){
                scrolleddown = true;
                $('#content').stop(true, false).animate({top:'0%'},500,function(){//show it
                    $('#topcontent').hide();//hide to original content, in this case "hi!"'s
                    $(this).css("position","relative"); //make it be able to scroll down
                });
            }
        }else{
            //below resets everything back to original state when user scrolls back up
            scrolleddown = false;
            $('#topcontent').show();
                $('#content').css("position","fixed").stop(true, false).animate({top:'99%'},500)
        }
    });
});
```